# Groovy & Grails Criteria for min,max dates comparison

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am working on groovy and grails `withCriteria` i need to implement the following logic in the criteria can any one help me to solve this

1. I have `start1`, `start2`, `end1`, `end2` dates in DB
2. I am getting `start` and `end` dates from front end

I need to implement the following logic

```
min(start1, start2) <= start &&  max(end1,end2) >= end
```

Please guide me to implement this

Thanks in advance

Comment: how about something like this def results = PostCodes.findAllByLongitudeBetweenAndLatitudeBetween(lonmin,lonmax,latmin,latmax)

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it without a SQL/HQL query.

```
def results = SomeObj.findAll( 'from SomeObj where min(start1, start2) <= :start &&  max(end1,end2) >= :end', [ start:start, end:end ] )
```

you can put the where-part into a `sqlRestriction` of your `criteria-query` if it's more appropriate